# NTRU cryptosystem

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography, irreducible-polynomials

In the NTRU cryptosystem we are dealing with convolution polynomial rings and we compute

$f(x)= T(d+1,d)$ and $g(x)= T(d,d)$ but when calculating their inverse in $R_q=(Z/qZ[x] / (x^N-1))$ 
and $R_p$ why can we only use $f(x)$ and not $g(x)$?

Definition :T(d1,d2) = a(x) : a(x) has d1 coefficients equal to 1 and d2 coefficients equal to -1

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $T(d+1,d)$ and $T(d,d)$? I was once observing a project studying/evaluating NTRU, so I do recognize the rings, but $T$ does not ring a bell. Would you mind adding the definition of $T$?

Comment: I've added a definition, thanks!

Comment: You are still assuming quite a bit from a would-be answerer. Also, if you write $f(x)=T(d_1,d_2)$ that looks like an assignment operation, where the rhs has a unique value. That is apparently not the case. Is this for the version of NTRU with $q=128$ or some such power of two, or for something else?

Comment: In other words, those $d_1$ $+1$s and $d_2$ $-1$s form part of the secret key, and they are chosen at random or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really guessing as to what the question really is, and my guess is that the OP wants to know why $f(x)$ has an inverse  in the ring $R_q$ but $g(x)$ does not.

If $g(x)$ has the same number of +1 and -1s as its coefficients this means that $(x-1)\mid g(x)$. As $x-1$ is a factor of $x^N-1$ this implies that $g(x)$ can never be an invertible element in $R_q$. For all elements $b(x)$, we have that the remainder of $g(x)b(x)$ modulo $x^N-1$ will be divisible by $x-1$ because both $g(x)$ and $x^N-1$ are.

The same argument does not apply to $f(x)$, because $f(x)\equiv1\pmod{x-1}$. Mind you this does not guarantee that $f(x)$ will have an inverse. It is still possible that $f(x)$ and $x^N-1$ have another common factor in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_q[x]$. IIRC the NTRU choices for $q$ and $N$ are designed with the view (among other things) in mind that $x^N-1$ has relatively few non-trivial factors (and these of a relatively high degree). This has the effect that with a ridiculously high probability the polynomial $f(x)$ has an inverse, if it does not have the trivial factor $x-1$.